# Getting error Invariant Violation tried to get frame out of range index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have create VenueList component. I want to display list using FlatList component in react native app. I am getting error: Invariant Violation tried to get frame out of range index (See screenshot).

Code:

VenueList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchVenues } from '../actions/venueAction';

class VenueList extends Component {

    componentWillMount () {
        this.props.fetchVenues();
    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text>{item.attributes.name}</Text>
        </View>
    );

    render() {

        return (
            <FlatList
                styles={styles.container}
                data={this.props.venues}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
        );
    }
}  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    item: {
      padding: 16,
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      borderBottomColor: '#ccc'
    }
});

VenueList.propTypes = {
    fetchVenues: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    venues: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    venues: state.venues.items
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { fetchVenues })(VenueList);
```

venueReducer.js:

```
import { FETCH_VENUES } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_VENUES:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

venueAction.js:

```
import { FETCH_VENUES } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchVenues = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get(`my_api_link`)
    .then( venues => 
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_VENUES,
            payload: venues
        })
    )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

The data which I want to display from API endpoint has json data as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "venues",
      "id": "nb",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Barasti Beach",
        "description": "Barasti Beach is lotacated in the awesome barasti beach",
        "price_range": "$$$",
        "opening_hours": "10:30-12:40/16:00-2:00",
        "organization": {
          "id": "GD",
          "legal_name": "Barasti",
          "brand": "Barasti"
        },
        "place": {
          "address": "Le Meridien Mina Seyahi Beach Resort & Marina, Dubai Marina - Dubai - United Arab Emirates",
          "latitude": "25.092648",
          "location": [
            "Marina Bay",
            "Dubai",
            "Arab Emirate United"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total": 1,
    "cursor": {
      "current": 1,
      "prev": null,
      "next": null,
      "count": 25
    }
  }
}
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you also post your `venues` reducer?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Added it please check it out.

Comment: when you console log state.venues.items what do you see?

Comment: @PritishVaidya Any idea why i am getting the error did you checked the screenshot ? I think the data is not passed correctly into react native FlatList Component

Comment: One more thing, can you also add the `action` for the same?

Comment: @SujilMaharjan I am new to RN can you please tell me if I `console.log(state.venues.items)` can I see it in browser console ? or where should I look for it

Comment: @PritishVaidya Added

Comment: when you do npm run ios/npm run android from the command prompt/command line, you can see anything that you console.log there.

Comment: @SujilMaharjan No nothing all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the the above response for the **api** **request**,

The problem is with the `payload` which is set in the actions. You need to pass the **data** from the api to the `Flatlist` since it accepts only arrays.

```
axios.get(`my_api_link`)
    .then( venues => 
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_VENUES,
            payload: venues.data
        })
    )
```

**EDIT:**
Adding in `VenueList.js` component (if the api is returning values inside `data` key):

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text>{item.attributes.name}</Text>
        </View>
    );

    render() {

        return (
            <FlatList
                styles={styles.container}
                data={this.props.venues.data}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
        );
    }
```

Comment: @Pritesh It doesn't work still getting same error after reloading. Should I restart server

Comment: Just reloading the js on simulator would work, `cmd+r` on ios and `cmd+m` on android

Comment: Have you checked above screenshot imgur link ? It is not working

Comment: Thanks got it. I have fixed it

Comment: You can add an answer for it and mark it as correct, if the issue was something else.

Comment: Please edit your answer  by adding this  http://jsfiddle.net/j3Lv5swn/ code to existing answer so that I  can accept your answer :)

Comment: only changing venue.data in actions will not work I also changed render() and renderItem() then it worked

Comment: I have edited your answer please accept it. Those changes in render() and in payload fixed the issue

Comment: If I want to add keyExtractor in FlatList then can I add this line as props for FlatList component -> `keyExtractor={this.props.venues.data.id}` but this doesn't work ? Can you suggest something else ? Because I am getting yellow box at bottom saying missing keys for items.

Comment: As in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist), `_keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;`, based on your `item.id`